# Are there any UI design principles about a website's nav bar should not on the right side of the window?

Tags: user-interface

I found many popular web application such as facebook, twitter and gmail designed their menu
bar on the left side of the window. I want to ask if this is caused by some design principles and psychological reasons? My thought is it should make more sense to put menu bar on right side since most people use their right hand to hold the mouse. Hope someone familiar with UI design can help with this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu's on the left ensure that you do not have to horizontally scroll in order to find your page navigation link or button.

Note that top of the page is also pretty common and in many situations just as useful, and minimalistic is now popular (show few options as possible/only options that are needed to make it quicker to get to your destination).

Answer (score 0):

Menus are usually on the upper left for a couple of reasons:

1. We read screens left to right, top to bottom.  That means that the upper left portion of any application (web or not) is prime real estate, and is where the most commonly-used items should live.
2. Unless someone resizes their window to be ridiculously small, the upper left corner of a website is always visible, which means that the menu is always immediately visible.

These two lead to a third reason to have it there:

1. Since most websites and applications operate this way, people expect menus to be in that location.  Moving your menu elsewhere breaks this expectation, and makes it more difficult to find things.  If you're going to break this expectation, you should have a good reason for doing it, and it should be so natural and such a better interaction that your users don't even notice it.

The mouse isn't the first thing that you should consider when you think about how you lay out a webpage (or an application).  Eyes are what you want to consider.  I might mouse with my right hand, but my eyes aren't necessarily looking at the place where my mouse is located on the screen.  Also, even though many people are right-handed, remember that more and more people are using laptops as their primary computer and don't bother with an external mouse, and thus are using a pointing device that is physically centered, not off to the right.

(I'll note that this answer only applies for languages that read left-to-right, like most Western languages.  Websites that are designed for languages that read right-to-left, such as Arabic and Hebrew, don't necessarily follow this.  They read differently, so prime real estate isn't necessarily that upper-left corner.)